# What could these characters i found on a robe mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification

I guess the first character is 福 meaning good fortune
And the second character is 得 meaning to gain but i have no clue what the third character should represent.

I not even remotely sure about my character guesses nor their meaning

- What are the characters present in the picture and what do they mean?

[image: probably Chinese]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right for the first character.

However, the second character is not 得. It is 禄 and means "official salary". The thrid character, 寿, means "life" or "age".

Combined together, 福禄寿 generally represents fortune or prosperity, high status or position, and longevity. It was originated from 道教 ([Taoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism)). You can find more explaination here on Wikipedia about [Sanxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanxing_(deities)).